# Google Purchase Status API HTTPS request

Tags: api

I am currently researching a way to use the Google Purchase Status API with just HTTP request calls, and I have hit a brick wall. I have an app setup with Google Play, and ownership of the Google Console account.

Basically, I just would like to check the status of a user's purchase on my server. The only information I should be using is the purchase token, product ID, and product package.

I have followed all the documentation on doing this at developer.android.com/google/play/billing/gp-purchase-status-api.html

The HTTPS request call I am attempting to make is this (product names and real strings substituted):

googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1.1/applications/(com.product.myproduct)/inapp/(com.product.myproduct.product1)/purchases/(myproductpurchasestring)?access_token=(myaccesstokenstring)

and my response is always this:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "androidpublisher",
    "reason": "developerDoesNotOwnApplication",
    "message": "This developer account does not own the application."
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "This developer account does not own the application."
 }
}
```

When polling my access token through this http request call:
googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=(myaccesstokenstring)

this is my response:

```
{
 "issued_to": "12345.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "audience": "12345.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher",
 "expires_in": 3319,
 "access_type": "offline"
}
```

So according to the documentation at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#webserver, I need to:

1. Authorise myself and retrieve a refreshable access token that is generated from 'Client ID for web applications' in the API access section of the Google API Console. I have done this.
2. Utilise this access token for google API calls in either of 2 ways: appending the string to the HTTP header 'Authorization', or as part of the HTTPS request itself with the property access_token=(mytokenstring). This part does not work for me, I always get an unauthorised message.

My question I guess would be: is it possible to use a simple HTTPS request call (without external library support) to retrieve the status of a purchased item without user interaction on backend servers?

I would really appreciate any help, most of the other threads are about how to go about getting a refresh token, but I have covered that already.

Answer (score 1):

ok, I figured out my own problem with the help of a colleague. Basically, my access token was being generated under an account which wasn't linked to the project in any way. It would be safest to use the owner of the project's google account when generating the access token.

Phew!